# Convexity with conditional probabilities

Tags: probability, convexity-inequality

Consider the random variables $X$, $Y$, and $Z$ supported on $\mathbb{R}^3$ and with joint distribution $P_{XYZ}$.

Can I say anything about $P_{XY|Z}(x,y|z)\log P_{XY|Z}(x,y|z)$ being convex or concave on $z$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, no, not without a lot of additional information about the functional form of $P_{XY|Z}(x,y|z)$.

Comment: Thanks. If $P_{XY|Z}(z,y|z)$ is Gaussian can we say anything?

Comment: Convex in what variables? It's  time for you to show your work: perhaps examples that make you think might generalize.